# How do you install ArcadeDB on Ubuntu?

Tags: arcadedb

I appreciate there is a Docker setup for ArcadeDB but I'm not clear on how to actually install it on Ubuntu? For OrientDB I followed this tutorial (https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-configure-orientdb-on-ubuntu/?expand_article=1) but even looking through the Repo am not 100% clear. Please could someone explain how to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's super easy:

1. download the distribution from GitHub Releases (https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb/releases)
2. unzip it in a local folder, then
3. run `bin/server.sh` from inside the ArcadeDB directory.

The only requirement is having Java 11 or major, but Java 11 is the suggested version.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain - how does one run it as a service? Otherwise closing the console disconnects.

Comment: You should configure it as a service (there is not service script for Ubuntu yet). Alternatively, you can always run it with: `nohup bin/server.sh &`.

Comment: I had created a simple documentation on setting up ArcadeDB as a service. Please refer: github.com/devcode100/graphdb-space